# Detect iOS version with PHP

Tags: php, ios5, browser-detection

For detecting Internet Explorer I use his line.

```
<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false) { };?>
```

How do I detect iOS 5.

Comment: Check out: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browserlist/ for a list of user agent strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP_USER_AGENT will return the following:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
```

If you are trying to detect iOS 5, do the following:

```
 <?php if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone OS 5_0') !== false) { };?>
```

Comment: Im sure you are correct. Icannot test it at the moment. Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity what if I wanted to check for multiple user agents

Comment: If you want to check for multiple user agents, then yes, get_browser() is the way to go. Just pay close attention to the note about keeping php_browscap.ini up to date.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem but needed to get the version number in iPhone and iPad using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. I suppose it is not completely reliable, but it worked for me:

```
<?php 

$version = preg_replace("/(.*) OS ([0-9]*)_(.*)/","$2", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

// for example you use it this way

if ($version > 5){
// do something
}


?>
```

Comment: I found that some user agents were not detected properly and returned as Mac OS X for the OS instead of iPad iOS (user agent detection probably needs updated) so I used this preg_match variant: preg_match( "/(.*) OS ?X? ([0-9]*)_(.*)/", $user_agent, $matches );

Answer (score 0):

If this is possible, [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) will be the way to do it.

However, since a User-Agent string is easily spoofable, and the list of browsers/OSes is a constantly moving target, this will never be 100% reliable. In order for this to work at all, you *must* keep the `php_browscap.ini` file up to date (see note on the linked manual page).

Comment: Would you mind giving a bit more detail with my if else equation on what user agent I am looking for with iOS

Comment: I can't, because I don't own an iOS device to test with. Sorry. You would have to test it yourself (just `var_dump(get_browser(null,true));`)

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy

```
<?php
   $browser = get_browser(null, true);
   echo $browser['platform'];
?>
```

The docs say

> Note:
>
> In order for this to work, your browscap configuration setting in
>   php.ini must point to the correct location of the browscap.ini file on
>   your system.
>
> browscap.ini is not bundled with PHP, but you may find an up-to-date »
>   [php_browscap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp) file here.
>
> While browscap.ini contains information on many browsers, it relies on
>   user updates to keep the database current. The format of the file is
>   fairly self-explanatory.